Trying to initialize class objects inside a struct is causing segmentation faults
I am attempting a program using C++ that prints text to a terminal in different colors.
I have the following code which features the Color class used inside the letter_template struct, which are the elements of an array of size 100:
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Works on little endian processors which mine happens to be
#define COLOR_PREPEND 0x001b;

class Color
{
private:
    char contents[6];
public:
    Color() {
        short prepend = COLOR_PREPEND;
        sprintf(contents, "%s[%dm", (char *)prepend, 0);
    }
    Color(int code) {
        short prepend = COLOR_PREPEND;
        sprintf(contents, "%s[%dm", (char *)prepend, code);
    }
};

typedef struct {
    Color *set;
    char c;
    Color *reset;
} letter_template;

letter_template essay[100];

int main() {
    // Initialize array
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(essay)/sizeof(essay[0]); i++) {
        essay[i].set = new Color(); essay[i].reset = new Color();
    }

    return 0;
}

The segfault occurs on the first iteration of the for loop. Using a debugger, I noticed that the contents of every member of essay had null values (0x0) for both the set and reset attributes, so I guess it couldn't initialize the Color objects. I cannot figure out why, though.
At first, what I was really trying to do was to have one long contiguous string of data in the order of color sequence > letter > color sequence > repeat. I know that what I have coded will not be exactly that, however I am at a loss for why it shouldn't be working, at least.
I am stumped because my Color class definition, as you see it, worked just fine before I put it into the class and typedef structure (as in, the sprintf statement, as you see it, worked fine when I just had it written in main). My contents attribute has 6 bytes, which I know is enough space for what I am sprintf'ing there.

EDIT:
I updated the code to exactly what I have, including the missing defines and includes. My compile command was:
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o; g++ main.o -o main.exe
Same issue as before.
Note: It was C code originally, which is why it looks like C code. The reason I am using objects and C++ things is because I wanted the utility of being able to set and reset specific colors on specific letters without hacking hard-coded strings everywhere, for which I wanted to use classes and methods.

typedef struct  { .... } letter_templates; wants to be struct letter_templates {....}; unless you are writing C code

Will sprintf(contents, "%s[%dm", (char *)prepend, 0) never create a string longer than five characters? Why are you using sprintf here? If anything you should use snprintf to avoid buffer overflows. Or better yet use std::string for all your strings.

My "contents" attribute has 6 bytes which I know is enough space for what I am sprintf-ing there. -- If the string is bigger than 6 characters, you did not make a deal with the compiler to cut the string down to size.  Computer programming doesn't work by blind trust -- you must write the code to ensure that the string will fit.

Also, (char *)prepend? What? Why? What are you trying to do? Why is prepend a short? Why do you need to explicitly convert a short value to a char *? And what is even COLOR_PREPEND? Please create a proper [mre] to show us.

please do not remove using declarations and includes from the code. They are part of the code, without them the code does not compile, adding different ones potentially changes the meaning of the code

Also, don't use pointers for the Color objects. There's just no need for that. Whatever resource you're using to learn the basics of C++ doesn't do a good job, I think. It's teaching you more C than C++. If you're serious about learning C++ then please invest in some good books.

fwiw, the issue is not with the array but the sprintf statements. We cannot compile them. Removing the lines that dont compile, your code compiles and runs without problems, the array is populated https://godbolt.org/z/YjPT7659x.

My "contents" attribute has 6 bytes which I know is enough space for what I am sprintf-ing there. -- Also, you could have just tried a little experiment on your own and increase the buffer size to 10, 100, whatever, but something much larger than 6 characters.  If you then saw that the crash didn't occur, then you would (or should) have done a little more research into whether those strings exceeded the buffer that was only 6 characters in length.  Then quite possibly, this entire question wouldn't have needed to be posted, since you would have discovered the error.

when your code has undefined behavior (eg due to writing out of bounds of some memory buffer) then it might appear to work for a while, until it does not. Just because some code does compile and produces expected output does not mean it is correct, that it cannot be the cause of crashes somewhere down the line

It segfaults because your code is trying to access invalid address  0x001b.

Don't edit your question to say "solved, fixed, thanks" or anything similar. Instead you can accept the answer your got below.

Unlreated: COLOR_PREPEND is a bad name. ESC would be a better one. You also don't need a macro for it. Just inline constexpr char ESC = 0x0b;.

Also unrelated: The first (default) constructor could be simplified by delegating the work to the second constructor: Color() : Color(0) {}

"the Color class nested into the letter_template typedef" -- Nesting has  a specific meaning of one class defined inside the other, struct letter_template { class Color {}; };. Your code does not demonstrate nesting. Also, typedef is not as precise as struct would be, since typedef does not have to define an alias for a user-defined type.

"Using a debugger, I noticed that the contents of every member of essay had null values (0x0) for both the set and reset attributes, so I guess it couldn't initialize the Color objects." -- This is good, and should lead you to trying to simplify your example code. It suggests that no object was initialized, so try dropping the array. Every layer of distraction you remove makes it easier to see what is wrong.

Your code exhibits undefined behavior, so anything is possible, and all bets are off.
In your sprintf() calls, the %s specifier expects a char* pointer to a null-terminated character string, but you are instead giving it a char* pointer that has been type-casted from a short integer value.  The pointer is not pointing at valid memory for sprintf to read from, thus it crashes.
You probably meant to type-cast the address of the short rather than its value, eg:
class Color
{
private:
    char contents[6];
public:
    Color() {
        setCode(0);
    }
    Color(int code) {
        setCode(code);
    }
    void setCode(int code) {
        short prepend = COLOR_PREPEND;
        sprintf(contents, "%s[%dm", (char *)&prepend, code);
};

On a little-endian system, this would happen to "work" to insert a 0x1B byte into your contents buffer. But this is simply the wrong approach and should not be done this way to begin with. For what you are attempting to do, use %c instead of %s, eg:
static const char COLOR_PREPEND = 0x1b;

class Color
{
private:
    char contents[6];
public:
    Color() {
        setCode(0);
    }
    Color(int code) {
        setCode(code);
    }
    void setCode(int code) {
        sprintf(contents, "%c[%dm", COLOR_PREPEND, code);
};

Or, you could simply hard-code the char directly in your format string:
class Color
{
private:
    char contents[6];
public:
    Color() {
        setCode(0);
    }
    Color(int code) {
        setCode(code);
    }
    void setCode(int code) {
        sprintf(contents, "\x1b[%dm", code);
};

Either way, do note that you still have a potential buffer overflow waiting to happen, if code ever contains a value < -9 or > 99.
At the very least, you should take in the code as an (unsigned) char instead of a int, and do proper bound checking on its value.  Otherwise, increase the size of contents to account for the largest int you will ever use.
Or, simply change contents to a std::string instead, eg:
static const char COLOR_PREPEND = 0x1B;

class Color
{
private:
    std::string contents;
public:
    Color() {
        setCode(0);
    }
    Color(int code) {
        setCode(code);
    }
    void setCode(int code) {
        contents = std::string(1, COLOR_PREPEND) + "[" + std::to_string(code) + "m";
        // or:
        // contents = "\x1b[" + std::to_string(code) + "m";
    }
};


The problem with this code is in this line:
sprintf(contents, "%s[%dm", (char *)prepend, 0);

Specifically in expression (char *)prepend.
In this expression you ask compiler to interpret prepend as a pointer to some memory buffer with char elements in it.
Since prepend is a number, instead of causing compile time error, it is converted to an actual address somewhere in a memory, according to example the address is 0x001b.
And then when you call sprintf computer goes to that address and tries to read char's from there.
Therefore you get a segfault.
The cast operation you are using, needs to be used with a pointer to memory you want to start interpreting as char's.
Therefore, in order to make the code work, you need to use (char *)&prepend.
Now it will not access uninitialized memory.
But whether it will do what you want or not, I do not know, since I do not really understand the application of this cast in this code.

sorry for the nitpick but the code has undefined behavior, what you describe "...computer goes to that address and tries to read char's from there..." is what could happen, but anything else could happen as well when executing the compiled executable.
